# Transform a list to a string

Tags: python, string, list

What is the pythonic way to perform the below transformation?

[a, b, c] -> "'a', 'b', 'c'"

Where a, b, and c are all variables holding strings.

Comment: What do you mean by "variables holding strings"?

Comment: Title says list, body says variables. Which is it?

Comment: a = 'one', b = 'two', c = 'three', ... n = 'infinity'. I have a list [a, b, c, ... , n] and I want the output to be "'one', 'two', 'three',... 'infinity'"

Comment: If you have a list, then why are you telling us about the variables?

Comment: Have you thought about using dictionary ? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just turn it into a string the normal way and remove the brackets that you don't want?

```
str(mylist)[1:-1]
```

Comment: Cool answer ! I like how you thought about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

<del>use the `.join` method on a string 

    ', '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])</del>

---

misunderstood the question

```
"'{}' '{}' '{}'".format(*[a, b, c])
```

or if you don't know the length of the list

```
 a, b, c = 'ehllo', 'sdf', 'sdflkj'
 d = [a,b,c]
 ("'{}', " * len(d))[:-2].format(*d).strip()
```

outputs, it's pretty clunky but it'll work even if the list elements are not `str`

```
"'ehllo', 'sdf', 'sdflkj'"
```

---

or in python 3.6

```
d = [a, b, c]
f"{d[0]} {d[1]} {d[2]}"
```

Comment: is it possible to separate with commas ie: "'ehllo', 'sdf', 'sdflkj'"

Answer (score 1):

A direct method would be

```
var = [a,b,c]
'\'' + '\', \''.join(var) + '\''
```

Assuming the contents of the variables is the character version of their name, (i.e., `a, b, c = 'a', 'b', 'c'`), the output would be

```
"'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format()`:

```
d = [a, b, c]
final = "'{}', '{}', '{}'".format(*d)
```

**Edit:** An answer inspired by the answer of @Stefan Pochmann

```
d = [a, b, c]
final = str(d)[1:-1]
```

example:

```
a, b, c = 'a', 'b', 'c'
d = [a, b, c]
final = "'{}', '{}', '{}'".format(*d)
print(final)
```

output:

```
'a', 'b', 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions are valid, I think, but here's mine:

```
final_string = ""
for item in list:
    if item != list[-1]:
        final_string += "'" + item + "', "
    else:
        final_string += "'" + item
```

Not very concise, but I think it's important to understand the process. This is the kind of thing I would write first when writing a new program, and refine it later. I like to know exactly what's going on, and sometimes single line solutions can cloud that a little. But I'd refactor eventually.